# ¿Es correcto modificar el código de una pregunta, en una edición?

Tags: discusión, ediciones-sugeridas

He reemplazado el ejemplo original, dado a la mala interpretación de mi pregunta original. Mi intención es abordar el caso en general, **no una edición en particular**, como parece haberse entendido.

Referencia a [Problema con suma con valor "NaN en JavaScript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/394539/problema-con-suma-con-valor-nan-en-javascript). Pregunta original publicada por [Sebastin Ignacio Astorga Busta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/194564/sebastin-ignacio-astorga-busta):

> > Al realizar los cálculos me da el error "NaN" en la suscripción
> > variable y el TOTAL
>
> ```
> var NPT = Number(document.getElementById('NPT').value);
> var NPSB = Number(document.getElementById('NPSB').value);
> var PPA = Number(document.getElementById('PPA').value);
> var SB = Number(document.getElementById('SB').value);
> var SB1 = Number(document.getElementById('SB1').value);
> var NUBE = Number(document.getElementById('NUBE').value);
> var SV = Number(document.getElementById("SV").value);
>
>
> function Data() {
>
>     var resultado = (NPT - NPSB) * PPA;
>     var resultado2 = resultado + SB1 + NUBE;
>
>     document.getElementById("TOTALSA").value = resultado2;
>     document.getElementById("SB").value = document.getElementById('SB1').value;
>     document.getElementById("NUBE").value = document.getElementById('VAN').value;
>     document.getElementById("SV").value = resultado;
> }
> ```

Edición propuesta por otro usuario:

> ```
> function Data() {
>     var NPT = Number(document.getElementById('NPT').value);
>     var NPSB = Number(document.getElementById('NPSB').value);
>     var PPA = Number(document.getElementById('PPA').value);
>     var SB = Number(document.getElementById('SB').value);
>     var SB1 = Number(document.getElementById('SB1').value);
>     var NUBE = Number(document.getElementById('NUBE').value);
>     var SV = Number(document.getElementById("SV").value);
>
>     var resultado = (NPT - NPSB) * PPA;
>     var resultado2 = resultado + SB1 + NUBE;
>
>     document.getElementById("TOTALSA").value = resultado2;
>     document.getElementById("SB").value = document.getElementById('SB1').value;
>     document.getElementById("NUBE").value = document.getElementById('VAN').value;
>     document.getElementById("SV").value = resultado;
> }
> ```

El problema es que esta edición a la **pregunta original** soluciona el problema planteado en primera instancia, por ende se invalida la consulta.

Comment: @BetaM. No, no responde. No es el mismo caso, porque aquí se altera la lógica del programa, no la presentación del código fuente. O sea, produce un código que funciona distinto al original.

Comment: Esa respuesta (no pregunta) es mía, ciertamente había un error de lógica por incluir ID de usuario en la consulta. AP realizó la edición y la acepté porque era lo que se necesitaba para llegar a la solución del problema. De hecho, no es la primera vez que me pasa algo así (distracciones recurrentes), pero solo acepto la edición si realmente es aplicable.

Comment: Si cambias la pregunta invalidando las respuestas existentes, es mejor que publiques otra pregunta diferente.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar'. No puedo eliminar esta pregunta. Sería mejor que se eliminara la respuesta, ya que no responde a lo esencial del tema.

Comment: respondía a lo que planteaste :) no hay ningún mal en la pregunta anterior

Comment: *Mi intención es abordar el caso general;* ¿Para qué pones referencias a preguntas en específico, si se trata de _un caso en general_?

Comment: @Gabitohh. Si no pongo un ejemplo, otro se quejara. ¿Tu eres el mismo gcoronel99 de antes?

Comment: @CandidMoe Si soy; por qué?

Comment: @Gabitohh. Estaba buscando una pregunta de gcoronel99 en que le cuestionaban NO poner un ejemplo. Las vueltas de la vida.

Comment: @CandidMoe ¿Me pasas la pregunta? Para saber a que te refieres, y como responde a mi pregunta inicial :)

Comment: @Gabitohh. Puede que haya sido alguna otra consulta de algun otro. Es díficil encontrar cosas aqui.

Comment: El nuevo caso expuesto, definitivamente está mal, las ediciones de código solo deben limitarse a formato y, en todo caso, a colocar como fragmento de código cuando corresponda. Esa edición es considerada como "Intento de respuesta" y debería revertirse... bueno, ya la corrigieron.

Answer (score 5):

### Aclaración:

Esa edición fue a una respuesta, **no a la pregunta.** La persona que edito la respuesta fue el autor de la pregunta. Esa edición fue aprobada por el autor de la respuesta.

### Mi opinión:

Teniendo en cuenta que:

- Esta edición fue aprobada por el autor de la respuesta, es decir se modificó el código con el consentimiento del autor.
- No le quita el sentido a la pregunta, **por que la edición fue a una respuesta**

Hubiera sido lo mismo si esta persona (quien edito la pregunta) le hubiera comentado al autor de la respuesta, y seguido el mismo autor lo editara.

Pienso que si la edición mejora la respuesta y fue el mismo autor original quien [aprobó](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/234376) la edición, esto no tiene nada de malo. Al final de cuentas, mejora la calidad de la pregunta.

Ahora bien, pienso que hubiera sido más adecuado que la persona que sugirió la edición hubiera comentado la respuesta (cosa que hizo), y luego el autor la hubiera editado. De cualquier manera, lo ocurrido tiene este mismo efecto, ya que **la edición fue aprobada por el autor.**

Comment: para agregar, quien edito fue el autor original de la pregunta y lo hizo porque el codigo mostrado no respondia al 100% su pregunta. No solo es una edicion valida, es mas que recomendable...

Answer (score -2):

SOes está dedicado a problemas de programación; el código es el corazón mismo del sitio.

El código de otra persona es sagrado; no se toca por ningún motivo, ya sea una pregunta o una respuesta

Si el código pregunta está equivocado, puedes publicar una respuesta mostrando el código correcto.

Si el código respuesta está equivocado, puedes agregar un comentario señalando el error.

Cambiar el código de otro es una falta de respeto para el autor original, por muy equivocado que esté.